# Passport.js fails to initialize when using SSL under sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js, passport.js

I am using Sails.js (v0.9.4) and passport(local strategy). Everything works fine.
I have requirement to set up Sails.js behind SSL. So I have:
https://www.mydomain.com:8080/api (I am forced to use 8080 as SSL port).

I start the Sails and it responds ok, at least those controllers that are open. However when I try to login, and passport start authenticating I get the following:

> Error: passport.initialize() middleware not in use
>       at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (D:\Development\TRYDEV\try-server\try-server\node_modules\passport\lib\http\request.js:44:34)
>       at D:\Development\TRYDEV\try-server\try-server\api\controllers\AuthController.js:37:17
>   at Strategy.strategy.success (D:\Development\TRYDEV\wrg-server\wrg-server\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:194:18)
>       at verified (D:\Development\TRYDEV\try-server\try-server\node_modules\passport-local\lib\passport-local\strategy.js:83:10)
>       at D:\Development\TRYDEV\try-server\try-server\api\services\passport.js:89:28
>       at D:\Development\TRYDEV\try-server\try-server\node_modules\bcryptjs\bcrypt.min.js:40:101
>       at D:\Development\TRYDEV\try-server\try-server\node_modules\bcryptjs\bcrypt.min.js:11:441
>       at d (D:\Development\TRYDEV\try-server\try-server\node_modules\bcryptjs\bcrypt.min.js:9:302)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:459:13)

This is the content of my local file:

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
port: 8080,
express: { serverOptions : {
    key: fs.readFileSync("ssl/5934652-localhost.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("ssl/5934652-localhost.cert")
}} }
```

Why does it not work when I change the local.js, I mean change it to https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your local.js file, do the following:

```
module.exports = {
port: 8080,
express: {
    customMiddleware: function (app) {           
        app.use(passport.initialize());
        app.use(passport.session());

        app.configure(function () {
            app.use(express.json());
            app.use(express.urlencoded());
            app.use(express.multipart())
        });
    },
    serverOptions : {
    key: fs.readFileSync(mc.httpsBindings.key),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(mc.httpsBindings.cert)
}}
```

Comment: How does it solve the OP's problem? Could you add some details about your solution for future readers?